Overfull \hbox with polyglossia and custom font
In my document, I noticed a considerable number of Overfull \hbox warnings. These occur when LaTeX should either hyphenate or adjust the spacing. This issue only happens when:

\setdefaultlanguage{french} is enabled.
\setmainfont{Noto Serif} is enabled.

Here is an example illustrating the issue:

\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,landscape]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
Des divergences d'opinions peuvent émerger de ces différences culturelles, 
notamment dans des notions communes dont les définitions varient.
\end{document}

The issue does not occur when \setdefaultlanguage{french} is disabled:

I noticed that enabling the microtype package resolves the issue:

\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,landscape]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
Des divergences d'opinions peuvent émerger de ces différences culturelles, 
notamment dans des notions communes dont les définitions varient.
\end{document}

However, I would like to understand what is causing this problem. Can anyone explain why this issue occurs when \setdefaultlanguage{french} and \setmainfont{Noto Serif} are both enabled, and if microtype is the proper answer to this kind of issues?
Note that I am using LuaLaTeX and TexLive 2023

all three affect TeX's ability to find good line breaks and the language setting also affects what counts as a good line break. changing the font just affects it for dimensional reasons i.e. the size of the characters and spacing depends on the font. so a larger font, say, makes it harder to break lines well (generally). microtype enables various features which provide more ways to get good line breaks e.g. by allowing fonts to expand a little bit to fill lines or to shrink a tiny bit to fit into lines, as well as various other microtypographical features. does babel give different results?

@cfr Yes babel usually works better, but I don't know why I've been told that polyglossia  is the new way...

Replacing \usepackage{polyglossia} \setdefaultlanguage{french} with \usepackage[french]{babel} gives the same result...

@nowox don't believe everything you read on the internet

@DavidCarlisle It is a good advice :) Do you have an objective opinion on this matter? I've read that polyglossia "is" better when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX because it supports OpenType

Babel might give different resuts in some cases but it does not in this one (polyglossia defaults to HarfBuzz which is probably a bad idea for latin scripts)

well obviously babel and polyglossia and latex without either package support opentype, so polyglossia supporting opentype is true but not very relevant to anything.

microtype generally improves typographic quality, as well as helping with line-breaking, so it is usually a good thing (at least for latin scripts - I don't know in other cases). there are some cases where you might not want to use it (e.g. it can increase file size) or where its effect is limited, but I can't see any reason not to use it here. (you can also fine-tune it to switch off features which increase file size etc., if needed.) it will be less effective with xetex than with pdftex or luatex because some features aren't supported for xetex.

@nowox I'm not objective, as I’m the babel maintainer, so I can't tell what's better, but babel does support xelatex and lualatex. Please, read its manual for further info. Note babel provides a macro to add easily patterns in the document with lualatex.

If you add \showhyphens{culturelles}, you see on the console
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 13--13
\TU/lmr/m/n/10.95 cultu-relles

and I guess anybody who knows a bit of French can understand why there is no hyphenation point between “l” and “t”. In hyph-fr.tex we see
    250 2crent. % mute syllable: massacrent (df) 28/02/94
    251 1cu
    252 1cû
    253 1cy
    254 .cul4 % -- as .con4 .cons4 (march 92)

(line numbers added for reference). This means that there can be no hyphenation when cul is at the start of a word, due to the high even value 4.
You might input cul\-turelles in order to solve the particular problem, but I heartily advise you not to.
If you can't reword the paragraph, you have the choice of typesetting it “sloppy”:
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,landscape]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}


\begin{document}

\begin{sloppypar}
Des divergences d'opinions peuvent émerger de ces différences culturelles,
notamment dans des notions communes dont les définitions varient.
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}


Without microtype:


As egreg has shown the issue here is just that the French hyphenation rules don't allow a linebreak at that point without help from microtype or other adjustments.
In comments you say

Yes babel usually works better, but I don't know why

polyglossia uses the same hyphenation rules as babel (and the two packages give the same result on the posted example) but in general the differences are most likely because polyglossia probably misguidedly makes the default mode HarfBuzz. HarfBuzz is far superior for many non latin scripts needing complicated shaping rules, but for latin script some technical issues mean that it can lose some hyphenation points.
If you want to use polyglossia you could use
\setmainfont[Renderer=Node]{NotoSerif}


to re-assert the default Node option in luaotfload, although it makes no difference to the linebreaking in this example.
